# How to tell when ForEachAsync completes?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, grpc

I'm using gRpc streaming and need to tell when a ForEachAsync loop runs out of elements so I can do something else. How would I do that?

Here is my method containing the loop:

```
private async Task UpdateProgress(string id)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ProgressServiceClient progressClient = new ProgressServiceClient(progressServerAddress);
            ChannelName channelName = new ChannelName() { Id = id };

            var timestamp = Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);

            _ = progressClient.ProgressReports(channelName)
            .ForEachAsync((x) =>
            {
                if (timestamp < x.TimeStamp)
                {
                    UpdateRow(x);
                }
            }, cts.Token);
           
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                if (cts != null && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Application.Current.Exit += (_, __) => cts.Cancel();
                    this.Unloaded += (_, __) => cts.Cancel();
                }
            });
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
```

Comment: Await the returned Task instead of discarding it?

Comment: Like @JohanDonne suggests or by checking [Task.IsCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted?view=net-5.0) if you want to check it at some later point.

Comment: I tried that. It seems that it never completes unless invoking the cancellation token cancel.

Comment: In that case you should check the `ProgressReports` method and find out why it does never return.

Comment: After doing some more research into gRpc, it seems that the nature of a stream is to stay open until canceled and therefore the loop doesn't ever return.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait before the foreach:

```
await progressClient.ProgressReports(channelName)
            .ForEachAsync((x) =>
            {
                if (timestamp < x.TimeStamp)
                {
                    UpdateRow(x);
                }
            }, cts.Token);

// all the items returned here proceed with your changes
```

No need to assign it anywhere, as you don't do anything with the result.

The article here has some good explanation on non waiting  on async tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/bc42358